# How can I get notified when money has been sent to a particular Bitcoin address on a local regtest network?

Tags: java, bitcoinj, bitcoin-testnet

I want to programmatically detect whenever someone sends Bitcoin to some address. This happens on a local testnet which I start using this [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file.

Once the local testnet runs, I create a new address using

```
docker exec -it minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1 bitcoin-cli getnewaddress
```

Let's say it returns `2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181`.

I put this address into the following [Java code](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/logic/btc/WalletObserver.java):

```
import org.bitcoinj.core.Address;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Coin;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Transaction;
import org.bitcoinj.wallet.Wallet;
import org.bitcoinj.wallet.listeners.WalletCoinsReceivedEventListener;

public class WalletObserver {
    public void init() {
        final NetworkParameters netParams = NetworkParameters.fromID(NetworkParameters.ID_REGTEST);

        try {
            final Wallet wallet = Wallet.createBasic(netParams);

            wallet.addWatchedAddress(Address.fromString(netParams, "2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181"));

            wallet.addCoinsReceivedEventListener(new WalletCoinsReceivedEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCoinsReceived(final Wallet wallet, final Transaction transaction, final Coin prevBalance, final Coin newBalance) {
                    System.out.println("Heyo!");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I start the Java application with this class.

Then I send some test Bitcoin to the address in question:

```
% docker exec -it minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1 bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress 2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181 0.5
068c377bab961356ad9a3919229a764aa929711c68aefd5dbd4c7c348eef3406
```

If I go to `http://localhost:3002/tx/068c377bab961356ad9a3919229a764aa929711c68aefd5dbd4c7c348eef3406`, I see that the transaction details.

[image: Screenshot of the transaction page]

However, the breakpoint in the listener (`onCoinsReceived` method) never activates.

**How do I need to modify my code and/or the commands I use to send test BTC so that whenever money is received by that account, `onCoinsReceived` method is called?** Is there a place where I can tell `Wallet` or `NetworkParameters` that I want to connect to localhost?

I am using version 0.15.10 of bitcoinj-core.

**Update 1:**

I modified [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/docker-compose.yml) and added following port mappings:

```
    ports:
      - "51001:50001"
      - "51002:50002"
      - "19001:19001"
      - "19000:19000"
      - "28332:28332"
```

Then I rewrote the `init` method so that I can connect to localhost and specify the port:

```
public class WalletObserver {
    public void init() {
        final LocalTestNetParams netParams = new LocalTestNetParams();
        netParams.setPort(50001);
        try {
            final WalletAppKit kit = new WalletAppKit(netParams, new File("."), "_minimalCryptoExchangeBtcWallet");
            kit.setAutoSave(true);
            kit.connectToLocalHost();

            kit.startAsync();
            kit.awaitRunning(); // I never get past this point
            kit.peerGroup().addPeerDiscovery(new DnsDiscovery(netParams));
            kit.wallet().addWatchedAddress(Address.fromString(netParams, "2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181"));

            kit.wallet().addCoinsReceivedEventListener(new WalletCoinsReceivedEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCoinsReceived(final Wallet wallet, final Transaction transaction, final Coin prevBalance, final Coin newBalance) {
                    System.out.println("Heyo!");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[LocalTestNetParams](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/logic/btc/LocalTestNetParams.java) allows to specify the port:

```
package com.dpisarenko.minimalcryptoexchange.logic.btc;

import org.bitcoinj.params.RegTestParams;

public class LocalTestNetParams extends RegTestParams {
    public void setPort(final int newPort) {
        this.port = newPort;
    }
}
```

I tried all of the aforementioned ports in `netParams.setPort(50001);`.

In all cases I get the following messages after `kit.awaitRunning();`:

```
22:16:34.245 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Attempting connection to [10.10.1.218]:50001     (0 connected, 1 pending, 1 max)
22:16:34.265 [NioClientManager] WARN  org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager - Failed to connect with exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:820)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.handleKey(NioClientManager.java:64)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.run(NioClientManager.java:122)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:66)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119)
    at org.bitcoinj.utils.ContextPropagatingThreadFactory$1.run(ContextPropagatingThreadFactory.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
22:16:34.267 [NioClientManager] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - [10.10.1.218]:50001: Peer died      (0 connected, 0 pending, 1 max)
22:16:34.267 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Peer discovery took 21.84 μs and returned 0 items from 0 discoverers
22:16:34.269 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Waiting 1502 ms before next connect attempt to [10.10.1.218]:50001
22:16:35.776 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Attempting connection to [10.10.1.218]:50001     (0 connected, 1 pending, 1 max)
22:16:35.778 [NioClientManager] WARN  org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager - Failed to connect with exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:820)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.handleKey(NioClientManager.java:64)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.run(NioClientManager.java:122)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:66)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119)
    at org.bitcoinj.utils.ContextPropagatingThreadFactory$1.run(ContextPropagatingThreadFactory.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
22:16:35.778 [NioClientManager] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - [10.10.1.218]:50001: Peer died      (0 connected, 0 pending, 1 max)
22:16:35.779 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Peer discovery took 8.752 μs and returned 0 items from 0 discoverers
```

`10.10.1.218` seems to be generated by `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` in `org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit#connectToLocalHost`:

```
    public WalletAppKit connectToLocalHost() {
        try {
            InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            return this.setPeerNodes(new PeerAddress(this.params, localHost, this.params.getPort()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException var2) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var2);
        }
    }
```

**Update 1:**

I tried to use `network_mode: "host"`.

If I add it to `node` as in

```
  node:
    image: ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest
    network_mode: "host"
```

I get the following error when I run `docker-compose up -d`:

```
minimal-crypto-exchange % docker-compose up -d
Creating network "minimal-crypto-exchange_default" with the default driver
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_postgres_1  ... done
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_geth_1     ...
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1     ... done
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1 ...
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1 ... error

ERROR: for minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1  Cannot start service electrumx: driver fail
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_geth_1      ... done
f68d0f25a0512399877bc55434513def810649e4fcf31a5a88ca3292d34): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:28332: bind: address already in use
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_blockscout_1 ... done

ERROR: for electrumx  Cannot start service electrumx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1 (8eaa4f68d0f25a0512399877bc55434513def810649e4fcf31a5a88ca3292d34): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:28332: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

If I add it to `electrumx` part as in

```
  electrumx:
    image: lukechilds/electrumx:latest
    network_mode: "host"
```

I get another error:

```
minimal-crypto-exchange % docker-compose up -d
minimal-crypto-exchange_postgres_1 is up-to-date
minimal-crypto-exchange_geth_1 is up-to-date
Recreating minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1 ...
Recreating minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1 ... done
Recreating minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1 ...

ERROR: for minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings

ERROR: for electrumx  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
  File "compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1166, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 697, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose/project.py", line 679, in do
  File "compose/service.py", line 579, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "compose/service.py", line 499, in _execute_convergence_recreate
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose/service.py", line 494, in recreate
  File "compose/service.py", line 612, in recreate_container
  File "compose/service.py", line 330, in create_container
  File "compose/service.py", line 939, in _get_container_create_options
  File "compose/service.py", line 1014, in _get_container_host_config
  File "docker/api/container.py", line 598, in create_host_config
  File "docker/types/containers.py", line 338, in __init__
docker.errors.InvalidArgument: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
[44262] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

**Update 2:**

If I comment out port bindings as in

```
  electrumx:
    image: lukechilds/electrumx:latest
    network_mode: host
    links:
      - node
# Port settings see https://github.com/ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest
#    ports:
#      - "51001:50001"
#      - "51002:50002"
#      - "19001:19001"
#      - "19000:19000"
#      - "28332:28332"
```

and run `docker-compose up -d` I get

```
 % docker-compose up -d
Creating network "minimal-crypto-exchange_default" with the default driver
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_geth_1 ...
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_postgres_1  ... done
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1     ... done
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1 ... error
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_geth_1      ... done
ERROR: for minimal-crypto-exchange_electrumx_1  Cannot create container for service electrumx: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior
Creating minimal-crypto-exchange_blockscout_1 ... done

ERROR: for electrumx  Cannot create container for service electrumx: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**Update 3:** I assume that the root of the error is that in my Java code I try to connect to the ElectrumX server instead of the actual Bitcoin node (`node` in `docker-compose.yml`).

**Update 4:**

I changed `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
  node:
    image: ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest
# For ports used by node see
# https://github.com/ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest/blob/master/bitcoin.conf
    ports:
      - "19001:19001"
      - "19000:19000"
      - "28332:28332"
  electrumx:
    image: lukechilds/electrumx:latest
    links:
      - node
# Port settings see https://github.com/ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest
    ports:
      - "51001:50001"
      - "51002:50002"
#      - "19001:19001"
#      - "19000:19000"
#      - "28332:28332"
```

Now I am getting different errors (full log available [here](https://gist.github.com/mentiflectax/189713b44041047145f006b695948c9d)):

```
11:33:51.865 [NioClientManager] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - [192.168.10.208]:19000: Peer died      (0 connected, 0 pending, 1 max)
11:33:51.865 [NioClientManager] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Not yet setting download peer because there is no clear candidate.
11:33:51.865 [NioClientManager] DEBUG org.bitcoinj.core.BitcoinSerializer - Received 168 byte 'alert' message: 60010000000000000000000000ffffff7f00000000ffffff7ffeffff7f01ffffff7f00000000ffffff7f00ffffff7f002f555247454e543a20416c657274206b657920636f6d70726f6d697365642c2075706772616465207265717569726564004630440220653febd6410f470f6bae11cad19c48413becb1ac2c17f908fd0fd53bdc3abd5202206d0e9c96fe88d4a0f01ed9dedae2b6f9e00da94cad0fecaae66ecf689bf71b50
11:33:51.866 [PeerGroup Thread] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup - Waiting 999 ms before next connect attempt to [127.0.0.1]:19000
11:33:51.866 [NioClientManager] DEBUG org.bitcoinj.core.Peer - Received alert from peer Peer{[192.168.10.208]:19000, version=70015, subVer=/Satoshi:0.19.1(bitcore)/, services=1033 (NETWORK, WITNESS, NETWORK_LIMITED), time=2021-11-06 11:33:52, height=5}: URGENT: Alert key compromised, upgrade required
11:33:51.867 [NioClientManager] WARN  org.bitcoinj.net.ConnectionHandler - Error handling SelectionKey: java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException: null
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:71)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.readyOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:130)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.isWritable(SelectionKey.java:377)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.ConnectionHandler.handleKey(ConnectionHandler.java:244)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.handleKey(NioClientManager.java:86)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.NioClientManager.run(NioClientManager.java:122)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:66)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119)
    at org.bitcoinj.utils.ContextPropagatingThreadFactory$1.run(ContextPropagatingThreadFactory.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

**Update 5:**

Someone suggested (in a now removed comment) that in the output of the application there is this `Peer does not support bloom filtering` message:

```
11:32:43.482 [NioClientManager] INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.Peer - Peer{[127.0.0.1]:19000, version=70015, subVer=/Satoshi:0.19.1(bitcore)/, services=1033 (NETWORK, WITNESS, NETWORK_LIMITED), time=2021-11-06 11:32:43, height=4}: Peer does not support bloom filtering.
```

So I tried to fork the original image and change the [bitcoin.conf](https://github.com/mentiflectax/bitcoind-custom-regtest/blob/master/bitcoin.conf) file to enable Bloom filtering:

```
peerbloomfilters=1
```

When I run `docker build -t mentiflectax/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest .` I get the following error message (part of remaining output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mentiflectax/d12a4332e074817770483407585a84b5)):

```
#13 922.4 g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
#13 922.4 compilation terminated.
#13 922.4 make[2]: *** [Makefile:8044: libbitcoin_server_a-init.o] Error 1
#13 922.4 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
#13 965.8 make[2]: Leaving directory '/bitcoin-0.19.1/src'
#13 965.8 make[1]: *** [Makefile:13765: all-recursive] Error 1
#13 965.9 make[1]: Leaving directory '/bitcoin-0.19.1/src'
#13 965.9 make: *** [Makefile:776: all-recursive] Error 1
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c tar -xzf *.tar.gz     && cd bitcoin-${BITCOIN_VERSION}     && sed -i 's/consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 150/consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 210000/g' src/chainparams.cpp     && ./autogen.sh     && ./configure LDFLAGS=-L`ls -d /opt/db`/lib/ CPPFLAGS=-I`ls -d /opt/db`/include/     --prefix=/opt/bitcoin     --disable-man     --disable-tests     --disable-bench     --disable-ccache     --with-gui=no     --enable-util-cli     --with-daemon     && make -j4     && make install     && strip /opt/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli     && strip /opt/bitcoin/bin/bitcoind]: exit code: 2
```

**Update 6:** The correct port seems to be 19000.

If I use port 19001, I get following errors after `kit.awaitRunning()`:

```
INFO  org.bitcoinj.core.PeerSocketHandler - [127.0.0.1]:19001: Timed out
```

Full log output is available [here](https://gist.github.com/mentiflectax/3384488a1ef77e524c68941053093cbd).

Comment: Maybe try run containers with network_mode: host.

Comment: Please, could you try connecting to the bitcoin node in port `19001` instead of the `50001` you are using? For instance, using the `LocalTestNetParams` class you created but setting the port appropriately: `netParams.setPort(19001);`.

Comment: @jccampanero If I use port 19001 (instead of 19000), I get time out errors. See update 6.

Comment: Is there any address, connecting to which the code works? You said you have a problem connecting to localhost. Is it only localhost, or do you have a problem in connecting any address?

Comment: @LajosArpad I can connect now to `127.0.0.1:19000`. But I'm getting the `java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException` exception described in update 4. This is what I need to fix now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @DmitriiPisarenko. Regarding the current problem, in order to try solving the issue you faced in update 4, just for test purposes, try running bash in the container - `docker exec -it minimal-crypto-exchange_node_1 bash` - and manually edit `bitcoin.conf` to include `peerbloomfilters=1`, then restart - by using `docker-compose restart`, for instance - your docker compose setup, and see if it works. The custom bitcoin image uses `alpine` without a specific version tag, maybe some change in the image or the OS can be the cause of the issue when compiling.

Comment: @DmitriiPisarenko Please, consider review [this example](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/0b5d40e49f58eb203be6d83aaafa28ad1acf539b/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/Kit.java) provided in the bitcoinj code, using `RegTestParams` instead of the proposed `TestNet3Params`. Then, try exposing your `node` service in the default RegTest `port`, `18444`, `ports: - "18444:19000"`, and as indicated in the previous comment, try modifying the bitcoin daemon configuration by including `peerbloomfilters=1`.  I hope that with this configuration everything works correctly.

Comment: Regarding the error while compiling the bitcoin binaries, it can be related to the memory available to your container: please, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11820). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your full setup with `electrumx` and the `ethereum` stuff present in your `docker-compose` file, but regarding your problem, the following steps worked properly, and I think it will do as well in your complete setup.

I ran with docker a bitcoin node based in the `ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest` image you provided:

```sh
docker run -p 18444:19000 -d ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest
```

As you can see, I exposed the image internal port `19000` as the [default port](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/185f880e78c92f65ee6befbba8a221912d3c2243/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/params/RegTestParams.java#L46) for `RegTestParams`, `18444`. From the point of view of our client, with this setup, basically it will look like as if we were running the bitcoin daemon in the host. Using your `LocalTestNetParams` class and providing the port `19000` as you indicated should do the trick as well.

Then, according to the feedback you provided in the question, I manually edited the daemon configuration of the bitcoin node in `/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` using `bash` and `vi`:

```
docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bash
```

And included the following configuration:

```
peerbloomfilters=1
```

After restart the container, I got a new address:

```java
docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress
```

Let's assume that the new address is the one you provided in the question:

```
2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181
```

Then, as suggested in the [Bitcoin documentation](https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/testing.html), in order to avoid an insufficient funds error, I generated `101` blocks to this address:

```
docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 101 2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181
```

I used `generatetoaddress` and not `generate` because [since Bitcoin 0.19.0 the option is no longer valid](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85355/method-not-found-when-i-use-bitcoin-cli-to-generate-blocks-under-regtest-mode).

Next, I prepared a simple Java program, based in the information you provided and [this example](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/0b5d40e49f58eb203be6d83aaafa28ad1acf539b/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/Kit.java) from the Bitcoinj library documentation:

```java
import java.io.File;

import org.bitcoinj.core.Address;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;
import org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit;
import org.bitcoinj.params.RegTestParams;

public class Kit {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kit kit  = new Kit();
    kit.run();
  }

  private synchronized void run(){
    NetworkParameters params = RegTestParams.get();
    WalletAppKit kit = new WalletAppKit(params, new File("."), "walletappkit-example");
    kit.connectToLocalHost();

    kit.startAsync();
    kit.awaitRunning();

    kit.wallet().addWatchedAddress(Address.fromString(params, "2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181"));

    kit.wallet().addCoinsReceivedEventListener((wallet, tx, prevBalance, newBalance) -> {
      System.out.println("-----> coins resceived: " + tx.getTxId());
    });

    while (true) {
      try {
        this.wait(2000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used a simple while loop to keep the problem running; of course, if will be probably unnecessary in an actual setup as it seems you are using Spring Boot.

Then, if you send some bitcoins to this address:

```
docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress 2N23tWAFEtBtTgxNjBNmnwzsiPdLcNek181 0.00001
0f972642713c72ae0fe03fe51818b9ea4d483720b69b90e795f35eb80a587c26
```

The listener should be invoked:

```
2021-11-09 23:51:20.537 INFO  [NioClientManager][Wallet] Received a pending transaction 0f972642713c72ae0fe03fe51818b9ea4d483720b69b90e795f35eb80a587c26 that spends 0.00 BTC from our own wallet, and sends us 0.00001 BTC
2021-11-09 23:51:20.537 INFO  [NioClientManager][Wallet] commitTx of 0f972642713c72ae0fe03fe51818b9ea4d483720b69b90e795f35eb80a587c26
...
2021-11-09 23:51:20.537 INFO  [NioClientManager][Wallet] ->pending: 0f972642713c72ae0fe03fe51818b9ea4d483720b69b90e795f35eb80a587c26
2021-11-09 23:51:20.537 INFO  [NioClientManager][Wallet] Estimated balance is now: 0.00001 BTC
-----> coins resceived: 0f972642713c72ae0fe03fe51818b9ea4d483720b69b90e795f35eb80a587c26
2021-11-09 23:51:20.538 INFO  [NioClientManager][WalletFiles] Saving wallet; last seen block is height 165, date 2021-11-09T22:50:48Z, hash 23451521947bc5ff098c088ae0fc445becca8837d39ee8f6dd88f2c47ad5ac23
2021-11-09 23:51:20.543 INFO  [NioClientManager][WalletFiles] Save completed in 4.736 ms
```

There is still a problem you mentioned that I haven't had the opportunity to test, and it is creating a new Docker image in which the `peerbloomfilters` configuration would be configured properly without modifying the actual container state. I think the compilation problem you indicated could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11820), basically, that the container didn't have enough resources to perform the process. If you are using macOS and Docker for Mac, try tweaking the amount of memory available to your containers, it may be of help. A change in the base `alpine` image used can motivate the problem also. I will try digging into the issue as well.

Comment: I think `docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddr` should be `docker exec -it 0aa2e863cd9927 bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress`.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriiPisarenko. Of course mate, thank you very much. I copied and pasted from the terminal and some characters got lost. I updated the answer.